# concatenate mutiple rows into one column based on certain conditions in teradata

Tags: teradata

I have a table as below

```
id   color   date 

1    red     01/01
1    red     01/02
1    yellow  01/03
1    red     02/01
2    red     01/01
2    blue    01/02
2    blue    02/02
3    red     01/01
4    red     02/01
```

The ideal output should be:

```
id    pattern 
1     (red, yellow) to (red)
2     (red, blue) to (blue)
3     (red)
4     (red)
```

The result displays two things:

1. The unique pattern within one month
2. Aggregate the unique pattern together within time range

Ex, we can see that id_1 has a pattern changes on Jan from (red,yellow) but on Feb, it only has one pattern (red). Therefore the final output should be (red,yellow) to (red)

The query that I have now is

```
select drv.id, extract(month from date) as month,
trim(trailing',' from (XMLAGG(TRIM(color)',' order by date)(varchar(10000)))) as pattern from
(select id, color,
lag(color)over(partition by id, extract(month from date) order by date) as prev_color
from table
qualify prev_color <> color
) as drv
group by id, extract(month from date)
```

The query is incomplete, since it didn't capture the movement from month to month, but is it possible that we may return it by month?

Is there any way that we can mix using XMLAGG and partition by? or can anyone give any ideas?

By Fred's method 1 which mentioned in the comment, the answer can be achieved by following query:

```
select drv1.id, 
trim(trailing',' from (XMLAGG(TRIM(color)'-' order by date)(varchar(10000)))) as pattern_mthly from

(
select drv.id, extract(month from date) as month,
trim(trailing',' from (XMLAGG(TRIM(color)',' order by date)(varchar(10000)))) as pattern from
(select id, color,
lag(color)over(partition by id, extract(month from date) order by date) as prev_color
from table
qualify prev_color <> color
) as drv
group by id, extract(month from date)
) as drv1
group by id
```

Thanks

Comment: One option could be to take your current query and wrap that in another that does an additional XMLAGG of the monthly groups so you have just one row per ID. Another would be to have a CASE inside the XMLAGG comparing LAG(month) with month in the current row, to decide which delimiters to append.

Comment: @Fred Thanks a lot, it works by method 1. I would share it in the question, But not sure how to put a case inside xmlagg, can u give more hint?

Comment: @fred I'm also not sure how to add () and to in trim statement, if I use statement 'trim(trailing',' from (XMLAGG(TRIM(color)' to' order by date)(varchar(10000)))) as pattern_mthly, it will return output like red,yellow to red to. Do you know how to get rid of the last 'to' at end of the output?

Comment: TRIM only removes occurrences of a single character and RTRIM a list of single characters. You could SUBSTRING (which would be easier if you added the "to" at the front instead of the end), or use REGEXP_REPLACE with a pattern that includes $ anchor so you only match at the end.

Comment: To use CASE instead of outer XMLAGG, instead of `TRIM(color)'||,'` you would do something like `TRIM(color)||CASE WHEN LAG(month) OVER (Partition by ID Order By month) <> month THEN ') to (' ELSE ',' END`

Comment: when I try to put the statement as:

Comment: You can't have LAG and GROUP BY at the same level. The CASE would have to be in a subquery